# attach the form to a comment, so that the form relates to specific comment

Tags: forms, theming

I need to solve the following. In the Custom Module I created a form that has a text box and click Send. Made for form validation functions and sabmita, then shoved the completed form to the variable template_preprocess_comment and brought the template comment.tpl.php
My code:

```
/**
 * Реализация template_preprocess_comment()
 **/
function comment_email_form_preprocess_comment(&$variables){
    $variables['email_form'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('comment_email_form_form'));
    //dsm($variables);
}
/**
 * Создаем форму, которая будет хранить данные email адресов бригад и отправлять письмо.
 **/
function comment_email_form_form($form, $form_state){
$query = db_select('comment', 'c')
    ->fields('c', array('cid', 'nid'));
$result = $query->execute();
$comments = array();
foreach($result as $value){
    $comments[$value->cid] = comment_load($value->cid);
}
     dsm($comments);
  $form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $comments[$value->cid]->brigade_select['und'][0]['value'], // ???
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Send'),
  );
  $form['#validate'][] = 'comment_email_form_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'comment_email_form_submit';
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  return $form;
}
function comment_email_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
  /*if (!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {
  form_set_error('email', 'Sorry. Your email address,' . $valid_email . ', is not valid. Please submit a valid E-mail address.');
  }*/
}
function comment_email_form_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
if($key == 'some_mail_key'){
  $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
  );

  foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }

  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];
  }
}

function comment_email_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    $from = 'noreply@example.com';
    $body[] = 'Email: '.$valid_email.'<br />URL: '.request_uri().'Вот такое вот хаха :0';
    $to = $valid_email; // Set this email address - emails will be sent to this email address! 
    $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'Website Information Request',
    );

    if (drupal_mail('comment_email_form', 'some_mail_key', $to, language_default(), $params, $from, TRUE))
    {
        drupal_set_message(t('Thank you for writing team has been sent successfully. Please wait for further instructions.'));     
    } else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Error sending e-mail. Please try again later'));
    }
}
```

Looking at the code it is already possible to see what the main task of the module, I need to send email to the address of the user who left the comment when creating brigades (node). The problem is that I do not know how I attach to the email address of the user text field by default. We have to somehow bind the form to the most comment.

See, initially under the role Brigade user is creates Brigade (node) it specifies an email address, then the user under the role of client creates an application (also node) and sends an email with a link to application your favorites brigades (this functionality I've already done).
After the brigade attaches with the comments file estimates below where applications are published after the pre-moderation estimates of these files, the hidden text field that brigade and an email send button.
So different from the brigades that left a comment, and then if the user liked one or the other brigade at a price of estimates, it sends them an email with a link to subscribe to the application, thereby concluding a cooperation agreement.
 Rules on means I can make the shipment after the creation, update, or view the comment, but not a permanent button to send an email to the client.
Sorry for my English